# Distribution to model availability of exposure to past events over time

Tags: survival, poisson-distribution

Sorry for the weird title. I'm not sure how to best summarise the question, so I'll provide an example.

Here is a histogram of movies I have rated on MovieLens, binned by release year:

[image: Year of movie release by ratings]

I propose this distribution comes about because of my age and the time over which I've been able to watch movies. It peaks in the 1990s because those movies were available and culturally salient over the years I've been watching movies. More recent bins are smaller because I've had less time to watch movies from those years. Less recent bins are smaller because movies from those years vanish into obscurity.

I want to model this, and processes like it.<sup>1</sup> At first glance I'd probably opt for a Scaled Poisson Distribution, (how far back over time do I need to go before I find a movie I want to watch), but it seems like there might also be some sort of survival-analysis-esque formulation of this, (i.e. in the population of movies, with what probability do they stop being watched after time *t*).

This seems like it should be a process that other people have looked at, but it's one of those frustrating cases where I don't know what to search for in the literature. Does a Poisson distribution seem reasonable? Do processes like this have a name? Is there a particularly straightforward formulation of this sort of thing which I've overlooked?

<sub><sup>1</sup> Specifically, and for context, I want to model data sparsity, and whether there are regions in sparse data that are reliably less sparse.</sub>